# How do I interpolate into React's hashhistory?

Tags: reactjs, interpolation, history

I have function as part of an onClick but don't know how to get contactId into the hashHistory.

```
  viewContact: function (contactId) {
    hashHistory.push('/${contactId}');
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
  viewContact: function (contactId) {
    hashHistory.push(`/${contactId}`);
  },
```